# Facebook SDK 4.17 login other user

Tags: android, android-facebook

I use Facebook login button in my app. If I log out with:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

and then log in again, I will be automatically logged in with my credentials. But how can any other user log in? How to force facebook show me login/password dialog again?